# Query To Get Consecutive Events If They Are Close Enough

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

This is my table structure:
monResults:

id Int(10)
monDateTime Datetime()
typeId int(10)

I need a query to get all monResults that have consecutive monDateTimes that are less than 1 minute apart and have the same typeId.  I want to be able to get X number of these events.  Mostly I don't know how to add the condition to make consecutive results be less than 1 minute apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some answers in this question which might lead you in the right direction:

[Group events by temporal distance in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875307/group-events-by-temporal-distance-in-sql/1875570#1875570)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this at all? Do you want to pass in a typeId, and have the query return all the ids that are less than one minute apart?

The problem is that you will just get a sorted list, you would still need to parse it in a program, as you will get, in a very contrived example, where monDateTime is a variant of a unit timestamp, for ease of typing.

```
id=1, monDateTime=3
id=5, monDateTime=57
id=2, monDateTime=63
id=3, monDateTime=120
```

So, you would need to determine in your application that the first two are one group, but the second and third are a group, so id=2 and 5 are in two groups.

If you loop through in a program and state that I want all the ids that are within a minute of a specific `id` and `typeId` then you can organize it in the program.

Then you can just use the `TimeDiff` function to subtract your specific id and the ids in the database:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  (@typeID = typeID AND @pdt >= monDateTime - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AS con,
                @typeID := typeID,
                @pdt := monDateTime 
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @typeID := NULL,
                        @pdt := NULL
                ) vars,
                mytable
        ORDER BY
                monDateTime 
        ) q
WHERE   con
```